# Cause of Current Spikes at Zero Crossing in LC Circuit Connected to 50Hz Mains

Tags: capacitor, ac, inductor, spike, lc-resonator

I set up a simple experiment where I connected 8x680nF 450VAC polypropylene film capacitors in parallel across a 250VAC, 50Hz mains supply. The capacitors, nominally at 640nF each, have an equivalent series resistance (ESR) of 1.5 ohms at 100Hz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk36BR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using an oscilloscope, I monitored the voltage across one capacitor and the current through the mains input wire with a precise current probe. The setup initially drew around 570mA from a 230VAC source:

[image: Voltage and Current Waveform]

The oscilloscope captures the following:

- Blue waveform: current (current probe sensitivity at 100mV/A, 50mV per division).
- Yellow waveform: voltage across the circuit.

Plotted graph showing current usage:
[image: Plotted Current Waveform]

An energy meter reported 421mA - 426mA with a power factor of 0, total energy consumption of 0W, indicating reactive power. However, the scope reported a peak current draw of over 500mA.

The oscilloscope indicated maximum current draw coinciding with the voltage zero crossing, aligning with the expected behaviour of the capacitors discharging.

When I introduced a big 38mH toroidal inductor (with approximately 4-ohm ESR (@100Hz)) designed to handle over 10A current without saturating in series with the capacitors, I noticed a significant current spike of over 2A at the zero crossing:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXbSqy.png)</sup>

[image: Voltage and Current Waveform - LC]

Plotted graph showing current spikes:
[image: Plotted Current Waveform - LC]

In this setup, the oscilloscope captures the following:

- Blue waveform: current (current probe sensitivity at 100mV/A, 100mV per division).
- Yellow waveform: voltage across the circuit as before.

An energy meter reported ~560mA, still with a power factor of 0 and a total energy consumption of 0W as well. However, the scope reported a peak current draw of over 2A!

This surge in current consumption persisted even with a reduced supply voltage of 50VAC, 50Hz from an autotransformer and when testing with other inductors rated for higher currents, as well as a common mode choke rated at 2A with a similar ESR.

Calculations for the resonant frequency of the LC circuit suggest an f0 of approximately 361Hz:

$$f_0 = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{L \cdot C}}$$

Plugging in the values:

$$f_0 = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{38 \times 10^{-3} \cdot 5.12 \times 10^{-6}}}$$

$$f_0 = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{0.038 \cdot 0.00000512}}$$

$$f_0 \approx 361.00 \ \text{Hz}$$

This is distant from the supply frequency of 50Hz, ruling out resonance as a cause for the spikes.

The question then is: What could be causing these large current spikes at the zero crossing? Intuitively, the inductor should mitigate sudden changes in current, yet the opposite is observed. What mechanisms might be at play here to cause this counter-intuitive result?

Answer (score 1):

> *The question then is: What could be causing these large current spikes
> at the zero crossing?*

It looks like inductor core saturation. A full specification of the inductor is needed to confirm this.

> *Intuitively, the inductor should mitigate sudden changes in current,
> yet the opposite is observed. What mechanisms might be at play here to
> cause this counter-intuitive result?*

Inductor core saturation.

Comment: I don't have a datasheet for the 40mH inductor, but here's the datasheet for the YHDC LN143-2 10mH CM choke that I tested as well: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1154089/YHDC/LN143-2.html. It's rated for 2A. In my setup, only one side of the common mode choke's winding was in series with the capacitor bank; the other winding was not connected to anything. I noticed similar spike in that setup as well. Since the capacitor bank draws less than 600mA when directly connected to mains without any inductors, it's well below the choke's rated current. Should it still saturate?

Comment: Oops, maybe the CM choke reached saturation because it's not designed for single-side connections? Normally, L and N together ensure the magnetic fields cancel out. But I connected only one side, which might have led to saturation by not allowing for this cancellation, effectively saturating the core! Probably both inductors I tested had their core saturated :(

Comment: @15Volts sounds like a good route to investigate.